Align entities to the back of RealityView
I want to align entities inside a RealityView to the back of the frame (e.g. make it "stick" to a window), is there a better way to do it than manually computing the z diff using GeometryReader3D?
struct MyView: View {
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader3D { geometry in
      RealityView { content in 
        let container = content.convert(geometry.frame(in: .local), from: .local, to: content)
        ...
        myEntity.position.z = -container.extents.z / 2
      }
    }
  }
}

I tried MyView().frame(depth: 100, alignment: .back), but it doesn't seem to work.

Screenshots would be helpful, annotated with what you’d like to see instead.
